# Wait until ActionListener is finished executing to collect data

Tags: java, string, swing, actionlistener

I have an ActionListener with code where I want a string to collect certain data once the ActionListener is finished executing. Below is a code of the important class that executes the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
JTextField UpperCaseEverything;
static int a = 1;
static String CurrentlySelectedText;
static String[] StringCurrentlySelectedText;

public Main () {
    super("Original Text");

    UpperCaseEverything = new JTextField("Click caps lock to capitalize the text (you can change the text, and as aforementioned, if Caps Lock is off, it will get your previous text before it was capitalized).");
    CurrentlySelectedText = UpperCaseEverything.getText();

    UpperCaseEverything.addKeyListener(
            new KeyListener () {
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

                }

                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK && a%2 == 1) {
                        String SelectedText = UpperCaseEverything.getText();
                        String UpperCaseText = SelectedText.toUpperCase();

                        UpperCaseEverything.setText(UpperCaseText);
                        a++;
                    }

                    else if (e.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK) {
                        CurrentlySelectedText = UpperCaseEverything.getText();
                    }

                    else if (a%2 == 0) {
                        UpperCaseEverything.setText(CurrentlySelectedText);
                        a++;
                    }
                }

                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

                }
            }
            );

    add(UpperCaseEverything, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(250, 250);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}
```

}

The most important information from the code that I am having trouble with includes:

```
UpperCaseEverything.addKeyListener(
            new KeyListener () {
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

                }

                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK && a%2 == 1) {
                        String SelectedText = UpperCaseEverything.getText();
                        String UpperCaseText = SelectedText.toUpperCase();

                        UpperCaseEverything.setText(UpperCaseText);
                        a++;
                    }

                    else if (e.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK) {
                        CurrentlySelectedText = UpperCaseEverything.getText();
                    }

                    else if (a%2 == 0) {
                        UpperCaseEverything.setText(CurrentlySelectedText);
                        a++;
                    }
                }

                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

                }
            }
            );
```

In:

```
else if (e.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK) {
                        CurrentlySelectedText = UpperCaseEverything.getText();
                    }
```

I want the CurrentlySelectedText String to collect all of the text from the JButton UpperCaseEverything after a user is finished with an input. That is because the String variable CurrentlySelectedText can collect the data that I don't want it to.

For example: if a user has typed: "Hi.", and deletes the full stop at the end, the sentence before the full stop was deleted is stored in the CurrentlySelectedText variable. If the user then clicks caps lock once, then the whole text (with the full stop removed) gets capitalized, as it should. However, if the user clicks the caps lock button again, then the "Hi." text is still saved inside of the CurrentlySelectedText variable, and not the "Hi" that is supposed to be saved is not saved in the CurrentlySelectedText variable. Consequently, the JButton UpperCaseEverything prints out "Hi." instead of "Hi". To solve such an issue, the String variable CurrentlySelectedText needs to save the text after the delete button has been clicked, but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the code is supposed to do.  When the user presses and releases the caps lock key, the whole string goes upper case.  When the user presses and releases the caps lock key again, does the whole string go lower case, or revert back to the original input state.

Comment: When Caps Lock is off, the text should return to what it was before caps lock was turned on.